# How to enable HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) in Tomcat + JIRA

Tags: tomcat, jira

It would be really helpful if anyone suggest me to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security) header in Tomcat

My JIRA application is running on tomcat and there is no Apache or NGINX at front.

I would like to set HSTS response header for JIRA application, Kindly please suggest how it can be implement in Tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for.
I took it from https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=30003&action=edit

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HstsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HstsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>maxAgeSeconds</param-name>
       <param-value>31536000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>includeSubDomains</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HstsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

package org.apache.catalina.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

public class HstsFilter extends FilterBase {
    private static final String HEADER_NAME = "Strict-Transport-Security";
    private static final String MAX_AGE_DIRECTIVE = "max-age=%s";
    private static final String INCLUDE_SUB_DOMAINS_DIRECTIVE = "includeSubDomains";

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HstsFilter.class);

    // The default is "0" like recommended in section 11.2 of RFC 6797
    private int maxAgeSeconds = 0;
    private boolean includeSubDomains = false;

    private String directives;

    public void setMaxAgeSeconds(int maxAgeSeconds) {
        this.maxAgeSeconds = maxAgeSeconds;
    }

    public void setIncludeSubDomains(boolean includeSubDomains) {
        this.includeSubDomains = includeSubDomains;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // Note that the HSTS header must not be included in HTTP responses
        // conveyed over non-secure transport
        if (request.isSecure() && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.addHeader(HEADER_NAME, this.directives);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(filterConfig);
        if (this.maxAgeSeconds < 0) {
            throw new ServletException(sm.getString(
                    "hsts.invalidParameterValue", this.maxAgeSeconds,
                    "maxAgeSeconds"));
        }
        this.directives = String.format(MAX_AGE_DIRECTIVE, this.maxAgeSeconds);
        if (this.includeSubDomains) {
            this.directives += (" ; " + INCLUDE_SUB_DOMAINS_DIRECTIVE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Log getLogger() {
        return log;
    }
}
```

Check the code on the link that I've attached.